# Using ILGenerator to generate method to copy and convert object properties gives InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, .net-core, cil, .net-standard, ilgenerator

I'm trying to generate a method that will copy properties from one generic object to another and if the property type is different, I want it to use a TypeConverter to convert the property value.
Eventually I want to scale this up so I can auto map IDataRecords directly to objects. But right now I'm having an issue with copying properties from one object to the other when the property type is different. The generated method works fine if all the property types are the same.

I don't understand why it can't be generated because I wrote an example method in C#  then looked at the IL, and the IL I'm generating should be the same.

Below is a simplified version, full code can be found at https://gist.github.com/DerekZiemba/468b84d7b5a5a289470859e261f17217

```
public static void CopyExample(StreetAddress target, DBLocation src) {
    target.Locality = src.Locality;
    target.Latitude = (float)TypeConversion.Float32Converter.ConvertFrom(src.Latitude);
}
```

Here's the IL generated by the CopyExample:

```
.method public hidebysig static void 
  CopyExample(
     class ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.StreetAddress target, 
     class ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.DBLocation src
  ) cil managed 
{
  .maxstack 8

  // [36 4 - 36 35]
  IL_0000: ldarg.0      // target
  IL_0001: ldarg.1      // src
  IL_0002: callvirt     instance string ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.DBLocation::get_Locality()
  IL_0007: callvirt     instance void ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.StreetAddress::set_Locality(string)

  // [37 4 - 37 87]
  IL_000c: ldarg.0      // target
  IL_000d: ldsfld       class [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter]System.ComponentModel.SingleConverter ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.TypeConversion::Float32Converter
  IL_0012: ldarg.1      // src
  IL_0013: callvirt     instance float64 ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.DBLocation::get_Latitude()
  IL_0018: box          [System.Runtime]System.Double
  IL_001d: callvirt     instance object [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter]System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter::ConvertFrom(object)
  IL_0022: unbox.any    [System.Runtime]System.Single
  IL_0027: callvirt     instance void ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy.StreetAddress::set_Latitude(float32)

  // [38 3 - 38 4]
  IL_002c: ret          

} // end of method ExampleILGeneratorShallowCopy::CopyExample
```

And here's the ILGenerator method that should produce the same output as the example above:

```
public delegate void CopyIntoDelegate<T, S>(T location, S src);

public static CopyIntoDelegate<StreetAddress, DBLocation> GenerateExactExample() {
    Type targetType = typeof(StreetAddress);
    Type srcType = typeof(DBLocation);

    PropertyInfo targetLocality = targetType.GetProperty("Locality");
    PropertyInfo srcLocality = srcType.GetProperty("Locality");
    PropertyInfo targetLatitude = targetType.GetProperty("Latitude");
    PropertyInfo srcLatitude = srcType.GetProperty("Latitude");

    DynamicMethod dynmethod = new DynamicMethod("ExactExample", typeof(void), new Type[2]{ targetType, srcType }, true);
    ILGenerator gen = dynmethod.GetILGenerator();

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, srcLocality.GetMethod);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, targetLocality.SetMethod);

    TypeConverter converter = TypeConversion.Float32Converter;
    FieldInfo converterField = typeof(TypeConversion).GetField(nameof(TypeConversion.Float32Converter));
    MethodInfo convertFrom = converter.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(TypeConverter.ConvertFrom), new [] { typeof(object) });

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, converterField);           
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, srcLatitude.GetMethod);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Box, srcLatitude.PropertyType);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, convertFrom);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, targetLatitude.SetMethod);

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    Delegate del = dynmethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(CopyIntoDelegate<StreetAddress, DBLocation>));
    return (CopyIntoDelegate<StreetAddress, DBLocation>)del;
}
```

Comment: Why do you even use IL code over compiled expressions which would be much more debuggable, much easier to write and have more or less the same performance?

Comment: It's better to provide complete example (example which can be copy-pasted, compiled without errors and on run - reproduce your problem).

Comment: Because it seemed pretty straightforward when I could just look at example IL then just generate similar IL.

I've created a full example.  800 lines with all dependency code (because of the type converters). https://gist.github.com/DerekZiemba/468b84d7b5a5a289470859e261f17217

Comment: You've failed to provide `unbox.any` with its argument. You're right, it is simpler in that you don't even need to understand IL to spot mistakes. However, compiled expressions have the distinct advantage of not producing invalid IL in the first place -- most problems with invalid IL are not so easy to spot. Also, make sure you're not just reinventing [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) and/or [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). This specific kind of code has been written many times before.

Comment: You need to load an instance _every_ time you use an instance method. You only do so twice.

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually solved it with the Unbox_Any.  I incorrectly assumed the "Any" part implied it could just unbox anything without additional info. AutoMapper and Dapper seem overkill for what I need.